# Convert Value from input to Object Array

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, hash

I have task which need to convert from input value to format object array like this:

```
[{
    id: 1,
    worker_id: 2,
    status:1
 },{
    id: 2,
    worker_id: 2,
    status: 1
 },{
    id: 3,
    worker_id: 2,
    status:1
}]
```

I have multiple row for my input.

```
<!-- row1 -->
<input type="text" id="id" value="1"/>
<input type="text" id="worker_id" value="2"/>
<input type="text" id="status" value="1"/>

<!-- row2 -->
<input type="text" id="id" value="2"/>
<input type="text" id="worker_id" value="2"/>
<input type="text" id="status" value="1"/>

<!-- row3 -->
<input type="text" id="id" value="2"/>
<input type="text" id="worker_id" value="2"/>
<input type="text" id="status" value="1"/>

<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

How can I do this in jQuery? Thank you for any help!

**updated**

Once I click button submit, can this format pass to text field?

```
[[1,2,1],[2,2,1],[3,2,1]]
```

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: Dont have, because now just getting start to understand how to use array object in jquery. Do you know how to do it ? see on updated

Comment: just an FYI - when using html the id attribute... it is mean to be unique across the entire page. I would stuggest that you name your id with the unique number i.e  id="id1" next row id="id2" for all elements in rows.. ie. id="worker_id1" next row id="worker_id2", there should never be more than 1 hrml id the same for the entire page. if you want to group then use class.. i.e elements which have something in common.

Comment: further to this... to solve your problem wrap each "row" in a div... then give the div a class. then look through the class... i.e. the "rows" mapping into props.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can structure your HTML to separate the groups of `input`, with `div` elements for example, then you can use `map()` to create the output you need.

Also note that `id` attributes must be unique within the page. In your case you could use a `data*` attribute to store the identifier for the given `input` element. Try this:

```js
var arr = $('div').map(function() {
  var o = {};
  $(this).find('input').each(function() {
    o[$(this).data('id')] = this.value;
  });
  return o;
}).get();
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" data-id="id" value="1" />
  <input type="text" data-id="worker_id" value="2" />
  <input type="text" data-id="status" value="1" />
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" data-id="id" value="2" />
  <input type="text" data-id="worker_id" value="2" />
  <input type="text" data-id="status" value="1" />
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" data-id="id" value="2" />
  <input type="text" id="worker_id" value="2" />
  <input type="text" data-id="status" value="1" />
</div>
```

The output format in your update (`[{1,2,1},{2,2,1},{3,2,1}]`) is not possible as objects must have keys and values. Instead you could use a multi-dimensional array. You can amend the above to do this:

```js
var arr = $('div').map(function() {
  return [$(this).find('input').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get()]
}).get();
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" data-id="id" value="1" />
  <input type="text" data-id="worker_id" value="2" />
  <input type="text" data-id="status" value="1" />
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" data-id="id" value="2" />
  <input type="text" data-id="worker_id" value="2" />
  <input type="text" data-id="status" value="1" />
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" data-id="id" value="2" />
  <input type="text" data-id="worker_id" value="2" />
  <input type="text" data-id="status" value="1" />
</div>
```

Comment: but if I want the value pass to only 1 text field which hold value like this can?
[{1,2,1},{2,2,1},{3,2,1}]

Comment: That's not possible as objects must have a key and a value. You could return a multi-dimensional array instead though. I've updated my answer to show you how to do that

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS NOT A COMPLETE ANSWER BUT SHOULD BE REALLY HELPFUL

suggested HTML, rename as you see fit

```
<!-- row1 -->
<div class"workerRow">
    <input type="text" class="workerRow_id" value="1"/>
    <input type="text" class="workerRow_worker_id" value="2"/>
    <input type="text" class="workerRow_status" value="1"/>
</div>

<!-- row2 -->
<div class"workerRow">
    <input type="text" class="workerRow_id" value="2"/>
    <input type="text" class="workerRow_worker_id" value="2"/>
    <input type="text" class="workerRow_status" value="1"/>
</div>

<!-- row3 -->
<div class"workerRow">
    <input type="text" class="workerRow_id" value="2"/>
    <input type="text" class="workerRow_worker_id" value="2"/>
    <input type="text" class="workerRow_status" value="1"/>
</div>

<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

jquery to target..

```
$('.workerRow').each(function(elem) {
   var id = elem.find(".workerRow_id").val();
   var worker_id = elem.find(".workerRow_worker_id").val();
   var status = elem.find(".workerRow_status").val();

    //map the values how ever you see fit.
});
```